# How to change the background color in new tabs without timeout (delay)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed an extension to the Chrome browser, that changes the background color of the pages on all windows and tabs already open. That extension is activated through an icon. Since activated, whenever the URL of a tab is updated, the filter is aplied to the new page. However, we see the new background color, only a few miliseconds later.
I would like to avoid that delay. How can I solve it ? 
Perhaps,I need to inject the code of `muda_conteudo.js` file, before the new page visualization ... If positive, how to do it ?

Segue o código:

Manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "CVD Images Adaptation",
  "description": "It makes the  still images adaptation  for CVD people",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "*://*/*",
        "activeTab",
        "debugger" 
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "on.png",
     "default_title": "CVD Images Adaptation"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "on.png", 
    "48": "off.png" 
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
var flag = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
flag = ! flag;
    if (flag){
    executeScriptsInExistingTabs();
}
else {
   cleanExistingTabs();
}
});

// Ação levada a cabo quando é criado um novo tab
// embora não faça nada, tem que estar aqui para levar ao trigger do    
// "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener"

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
  if (flag){
    if (info.status == "complete") {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"muda_conteudo.js"});
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id})
    }
  }
});

function executeScriptsInExistingTabs(){
    chrome.windows.getAll(null, function(wins) {
      for (var j = 0; j < wins.length; ++j) {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(wins[j].id, function(tabs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("chrome://") != 0) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { file: 'muda_conteudo.js' });
              chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tabs[i].id});
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
}


function cleanExistingTabs(){
    chrome.windows.getAll(null, function(wins) {
      for (var j = 0; j < wins.length; ++j) {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(wins[j].id, function(tabs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("chrome://") != 0) {
               chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tabs[i].id});
               chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {code:'window.location.href=window.location.href'});
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```

muda_conteudo.js

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Ok course, I intend to use another `muda_conteudo.js` file, in the future. But, as I am making experiments, I chose a file with only one and simple instuction, for tests.

I thought to use the function `addEventListener` with the parameter `beforeload`, but I can not operationalize it. I don't know if it is lack of skills or if that function does not produce the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to reduce the delay between the page load and script injection is to specify the 'runAt' field in the injectDetails for calls to chrome.tabs.executeScript as 'document_start'.  This will tell chrome to inject the script as soon as possible, rather than waiting until document.idle (which is the default for performance reasons).

e.g.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
     tabs[i].id,
     { file: 'muda_conteudo.js', runAt: 'document_start' });
```

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-InjectDetails for more details.

Cheers!